# F# Function Addition

Tags: math, f#, functional-programming

I want to implement a (simple) mathematical function addition in F#, meaning:

Imagine **F** being the field of all functions, which map an element of **A** to an element of **B**:
[image]

Then, my "function addition" should be defined as follows:
[image]

I have tried the following code to implement the function addition as the operator `!+`:

```
let inline (!+) (f1 : ^a -> ^b, f2 : ^a -> ^b) : ^a -> ^b =
    let f (x : ^a) : ^b =
        (f1 x) + (f2 x)
    f
```

However, if I want to compile the following lines, I will get an error:

```
let f1 x : float = -x // negate x
let f2 x : float = 2. * x // multiply by 2
let f3 = f1 !+ f2 //error : Expexceted `float`, got `'a -> 'b`
```

I am pretty sure, that it is caused by some simple logical error, but I was yet unable to find it.
My question therefore is: How does one define a function addition in F#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quite close !
Two main issues:

- `!+` is a unary operator. See [the rules](http://www.readcopyupdate.com/blog/2014/09/10/custom-ops-associativity-precedence.html) for F# operators.
- your function is taking tuples. It's not curried.

Correct it and you get it working:

```
let inline (++) (f1 : ^a -> ^b) (f2 : ^a -> ^b) : ^a -> ^b =
    let f (x : ^a) : ^b =
        (f1 x) + (f2 x)
    f

let f1 x : float = -x
let f2 x : float = 2. * x
let f3 = f1 ++ f2
```

Let me add that you don't need any type annotation, F# will figure it out for you:

```
let inline (++) f1 f2 x = f1 x + f2 x
```

If you read the signature you'll notice that your functions can have any input type, just the result types should match:

```
let inline f1 x = -(float x)
let f2 x : float = float (2 * x)
let f3 = f1 ++ f2
```